# Why is my Rails not running on new development environment for existing project/repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just installed a Ruby development environment on a new computer to augment my other. So I am 99.9% sure I have all the I's dotted and T's crossed for software etc (ruby version, rails, homebrew... etc).

I successfully clone the repo to my local environment.

When I run `rails s` I get the error:

```
rbenv: version `2.4.4' is not installed (set by /Users/brianruby/code/brian-welch/training_repo/.ruby-version)
```

I then run from the repo directory, `ruby -v`:

```
rbenv: version `2.4.4' is not installed (set by /Users/brianruby/code/brian-welch/training_repo/.ruby-version)
```

Then from my home directory, `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

(*Not a clue why that command won't work within the project directory*)

I then try to alter the `.ruby-version` file to match 2.5.3, as well as the `Gemfile`. I again run: `rails s`, and it yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /Users/brianruby/code/brian-welch/training_repo/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/brianruby/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/brianruby/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that the project specifies a Ruby version through `.ruby-version` as you noticed. You should probably install the specified version if you plan to work on that project. I see you have `rbenv` installed and depending on some local specifics you could achieve that through running `rbenv install 2.4.4` (if you have `ruby-build` installed as a plugin for `rbenv`) or `ruby-build 2.4.4` (if `ruby-build` is installed standalone). If you don't have `ruby-build` you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build .

The second problem is that you don't have the `bundler` gem installed. You can fix this by running `gem install bundler` . Keep in mind that this installs the gem for the currently selected Ruby version and you have to install it for each one you are going to use with this project.